# Linux SUSE - how to check (from root) if a package is already installed?

Tags: linux, rpm, sles

Simple question on SUSE Linux Enterprise Server 11 SP1 (simple for someone who's not a total ignorant on the topic like me I am guessing): **how do I check from root if a given package is already installed for all the users?**

Any help appreciated!

Note: I am trying to check if tightvnc server is already installed on my distro - Guess not since if I run `dbus-launch vncserver` I get a 'command not found' message

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For SLES11 SP1, the key command is `zypper`

```
server:/ # zypper se tightvnc
Loading repository data...
Reading installed packages...

S | Name     | Summary                          | Type   
--+----------+----------------------------------+--------
i | tightvnc | A virtual X-Window System server | package
```

"se" is the short version of 'search'. Also more standard `rpm -q tightvnc` works as well.

```
server:/ # rpm -q tightvnc
tightvnc-1.3.10-2.1.x86_64
```

For zypper the "info" command will give you details about the package, including versions.

Comment: thanks man - you rock, will give it asap. Any clue why dbus-launch vncserver is 'not found'? Does it have anything to do with the fact that that particular package is not installed? cheers

Comment: How to check local package without an attempt to connect to repository?